# Heston calibration using Quantlib and Python: failure in BlackVarianceSurface function

Tags: programming, quantlib, heston

I have an error when trying to use the fucntion BlackVarianceSurface from quantlib.

Can you help me?

the error is RunTime Error: dates must be sorted unique.

```
    def IndexVolatilities2(calculation_date):

    spot = 2184.56
    strikePerc = [0.8,0.9,0.95,0.975,1,1.025,1.05,1.10,1.2]
    risk_free_rate = 0.0213
    dividend_rate = 0.006

    #vol is a sample matrix of volatility quote by expiry and strike
    #Following is a sample matrix of volatility quote by exipiry and strike. 
    #The volatilities are log-normal volatilities and can be interpolated to construct the implied volatility surface.

    p1m= calculation_date + ql.Period(1, ql.Months)
    p2m= calculation_date+ ql.Period(2, ql.Months)
    p3m= calculation_date+ ql.Period(3, ql.Months)
    p6m= calculation_date+ ql.Period(6, ql.Months)
    p9m= calculation_date+ ql.Period(9, ql.Months)
    p18m= calculation_date+ ql.Period(18, ql.Months)
    p1Y = calculation_date + ql.Period(1, ql.Years)
    p3Y = calculation_date + ql.Period(3, ql.Years)
    p4Y = calculation_date + ql.Period(4, ql.Years)
    p5Y = calculation_date + ql.Period(5, ql.Years)
    p7Y = calculation_date + ql.Period(7, ql.Years)
    p10Y = calculation_date + ql.Period(10, ql.Years)

    expiration_dates = [p1m, p2m, p3m, p6m, p9m,p18m,p1Y,p3Y,p4Y,p5Y,p7Y,p10Y]

    strikes = [p*spot for p in strikePerc]
    data =[
    [27.18000,  22.31000,   17.31000,   14.81000,   11.84000,   8.97000,    10.14000,   14.59000,   19.44000],
    [26.14000,  20.64000,   16.78000,   15.05000,   12.81000,   10.48000,   9.91000,    13.03000,   17.77000],
    [25.28000,  19.84000,   16.73000,   15.25000,   13.35000,   11.36000,   10.36000,   12.26000,   16.66000],
    [22.48000,  18.76000,   16.62000,   15.45000,   14.19000,   12.92000,   11.85000,   11.09000,   12.06000],
    [20.68000,  18.55000,   16.84000,   15.82000,   14.73000,   13.65000,   12.71000,   11.58000,   12.06000],
    [20.26000,  18.43000,   16.93000,   16.05000,   15.13000,   14.23000,   13.41000,   12.24000,   12.18000],
    [20.25000,  18.20000,   16.90000,   16.21000,   15.51000,   14.82000,   14.19000,   13.18000,   12.47000],
    [20.03000,  18.02000,   16.84000,   16.23000,   15.63000,   15.05000,   14.50000,   13.61000,   12.78000],
    [19.81000,  17.93000,   16.93000,   16.43000,   15.95000,   15.48000,   15.05000,   14.32000,   13.44000],
    [19.74000,  17.99000,   17.12000,   16.69000,   16.28000,   15.89000,   15.53000,   14.90000,   14.08000],
    [19.75000,  18.14000,   17.36000,   16.99000,   16.63000,   16.30000,   15.98000,   15.43000,   14.66000],
    [19.98000,  18.59000,   17.95000,   17.65000,   17.36000,   17.10000,   16.84000,   16.40000,   15.74000],
    [20.60000,  19.46000,   18.96000,   18.73000,   18.51000,   18.30000,   18.11000,   17.76000,   17.22000]]
    return expiration_dates,strikes,data,spot, risk_free_rate,dividend_rate

    calendar = ql.UnitedStates()
day_count = ql.Actual365Fixed()
calculation_date = ql.Date(25, 9, 2019)

#expiration_dates,strikes,data,spot, risk_free_rate,dividend_rate = IndexVolatilities1()
expiration_dates,strikes,data,spot, risk_free_rate,dividend_rate = IndexVolatilities2(calculation_date)

#build the vol surface (implied vols surface) and dividend and the interest rate curve
hestonParams=  HestonParameters(calculation_date, calendar, day_count, spot, risk_free_rate, dividend_rate, len(expiration_dates), strikes, data)
dividend_ts, flat_ts, implied_vols = hestonParams.dividend_ts, hestonParams.flat_ts, hestonParams.implied_vols

# Now the Black volatility surface can be constructed using the BlackVarianceSurface method.
black_var_surface = ql.BlackVarianceSurface(calculation_date, calendar, expiration_dates, strikes,implied_vols, day_count)
```

Answer (score 2):

"Dates must be sorted unique".  "Unique", so you can't have repeated dates in the inputs you're passing.   You have two copies of 1Y.  You probably wanted the second to be 2Y.

"Sorted", so you can't have 18M before 1Y.  They have to be in the correct order in time.

Comment: Thanks for the remark. I have corrected it but still having the same error.       expiration_dates = [p1m, p2m, p3m, p6m, p9m,p18m,p1Y,p3Y,p4Y,p5Y,p7Y,p10Y]

Comment: I've edited the answer.

Comment: Thanks. how do you sort the vector of dates?